Install Rocky Linux 9.4 on MacBook Air (13-inch, Early 2015)
Yesterday, I decided to install Rocky Linux 9.4
https://download.rockylinux.org/pub/rocky/9/isos/x86_64/Rocky-9.4-x86_64-dvd.iso on my MBA (MacBook Air, 13-inch, Early 2015) https://support.apple.com/en-us/111956
Previously I had installed on other PC the CentOS 8 (dual boot with Windows), and previously using VirtualBox. This is not my first time installing RHEL brother.
When I started to install Rocky Linux I deleted previous partition (with Rocky Linux installer, maybe I do some bad or missing anything), but my problem is when the installation finished continue appearing the Apple Logo and my mac tries to download the macOS and my Linux is not starting.
support.apple.com/mac/startup
I made a USB with GParted Live (https://gparted.org/download.php) with Etcher (https://etcher.balena.io/#download-etcher) to delete all old partitions to try to install Rocky Linux again, but my MBA doesn't recognize this USB.
Firstly, I would like to delete old macOS partitions with GParted, but I don't know how to do it.
Do I need to disable some security of my MBA?
Secondly, Why my MBA is not recognizing my Rocky Linux 9.4?

I partially got GParted to boot on my MacBook Air with https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=18pMiuFfWuY&t=70s
(I formatted as MSDOS with Rufus on Windows 10, I downloaded gparted-live-1.6.0-5-amd64.zip and I pasted its content in my USB).
